# Using MFMailComposeViewController in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app I need to implement (send mail) functionality. 
I used **MFMailComposeViewController** to implement this functionality. 
But I faced a strange problem,when the **MFMailComposeViewController** can't send the mail, there is a strange pop up appear, like this: 
[image: strange alert view]

and my code is :

```
let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["in**@******.***"])

        mailComposerVC.setSubject(getEmailSubject())

        let message = "Name: \(self.nameTextField.text!) \n Email: \(self.emailTextField.text!) \n Phone: \(self.phoneTextField.text!) \n \(self.messageTextView.text!)"

        print(message)

        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(message, isHTML: false)

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            self.presentViewController(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()

        }
```

anyone faced this problem? 
please help.

Thanks

Comment: A Google search shows this: https://github.com/Legoless/iOS-Localization/blob/master/7.0.4/iPhone/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/English.lproj/Main.strings.json, is that somehow related to your project?

Comment: I think there is problem with localization. If you test on simulator ignore it sometimes happens :)

Comment: @DeVladinci nooo I test it on device not on the simulator :(

Comment: @MartinR wooow! that exactly what happen with me. but i don't know if it's possible to edit it .. do you know what this link is ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `MFMailComposeViewController` via simulator will probably fail.
Best practise will be checking it on a real device.

I'm attaching working code from one of my projects.

```
 func shareMail()
    {
        let mailClass:AnyClass?=NSClassFromString("MFMailComposeViewController")
        if(mailClass != nil)
        {
            if((mailClass?.canSendMail()) != nil)
            {
                displayComposerSheet()
            }
            else
            {
                launchMailAppOnDevice()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            launchMailAppOnDevice()
        }
    }
    func launchMailAppOnDevice()
    {
        let recipients:NSString="";
        let body:NSString = "hey"
        var email:NSString="\(recipients) \(body)"
        email=email.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: email as String)!)
    }
    func displayComposerSheet()
    {
        let picker: MFMailComposeViewController=MFMailComposeViewController()
        picker.mailComposeDelegate=self;
        picker .setSubject("Check out this photo I've edited with PICCELL! ")
        picker.setMessageBody(bodyFor, isHTML: true)
        let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sendImage)!

        picker.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "images.png")

        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError?)
    {
        if result == MFMailComposeResultSent
        {
           animateFinished(btn_email)
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Don't forget to add the delegates :

```
UINavigationControllerDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

Comment: no i've try it on device :( 
it's all about the Localazations files ..
I don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: @Rawan I'm sorry Rawan. thats a far as i can assist, I never used local strings before. Try sending email without first local first, maybe it's not the problem